# Why is my motor working only at a certain speed in one direction ? (with BTS7960 and PWM)

Tags: motor, pwm

I designed a simple door for the chicken, that opens at dawn and closes at dusk.
Mechanically, it is a sliding door pulled up by a wire, and a 12V DC motor (actually an old cordless drill) that acts as a winch.
The motor is driven by a BTS7960 double half-bridge, and the microcontroller is a raspberry pico programmed with micropython. Nothing special with the wiring, you can find details on the pin numbers in the full code provided below.

I used to go full power in both directions, and it was working good, but I think it's too powerful and brutal so I want to reduce the speed of the motor using PWM, which the driver is designed to handle.

Old working code (extract), no pwm :

```
enable = Pin(PIN_ENABLE, Pin.OUT)
rpwm = Pin(PIN_RPWM, Pin.OUT)
# start motor
enable.value(1)
rpwm.value(1)
# [...]
# brake and stop motor 
rpwm.value(0)
sleep(1)
enable.value(0)
```

My problem is that when I implemented PWM, I started to experiment a weird behavior : in one direction all is fine and I can freely vary the speed (values of MOTOR_DUTY_CYCLE between 0 and 65535), but in the other direction, values other than 10000 don't work and the motor doesn't start at all.

New code (extract) :

```
MOTOR_DUTY_CYLE = 10000
enable = Pin(PIN_ENABLE, Pin.OUT)
rpwm = PWM(Pin(PIN_RPWM, Pin.OUT))
# start motor
enable.value(1)
rpwm.duty_u16(MOTOR_DUTY_CYLE)
# [...]
# brake and stop motor 
rpwm.duty_u16(0)
sleep(1)
enable.value(0)
```

I tried changing the frequency of the pwm to 1000 Hz, without any effect. I didn't visualize the signals with an oscilloscope because I don't have grid power near the installation. I saw afterwards that the driver handles "up to 25kHz", I should probably try this value, though it doesn't say there's a minimum. I'm not sure what is the default frequency of the pico either. But anyway, what puzzles me most is why is it working in one direction and not the other ?

Here is the complete code : https://gitlab.com/guillaume.deshors/carapoule/-/blob/28f6ecd979c378a5d879f6a9827308ccc6881b43/main.py

Comment: I just tested 25kHz. It now works in both directions with a value of 20000, but still not 30000, 30001 or 40000. This is OK for the purpose of the chicken door, but not for my peace of mind...